# Terraform iterate over a nested iterate

Tags: terraform

I have this terraform code and it has two dynamic blocks:

```
# block one
  dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pools

    content {
      name      = each.key
      fqdns     = each.value["fqdns"]
      ip_addresses = each.value["ip_addresses"]
    }
  }    

# block two
  dynamic "request_routing_rule" {
    for_each = var.request_routing_rules

    content {
      name      = each.key
      rule_type     = each.value["rule_type"]
      http_listener_name = each.value["http_listener_name"]
      backend_address_pool_name = <How to get the names of the block1's address pools here>
      backend_http_settings_name = each.value["backend_http_settings_name"]
    }
  }
```

And in the `block1` I have iterate over multiple address pools namely `pool1`, `pool2`, `pool3` and so on, in the `block2`, I need to get the values of the each block iteration and assign it to the value `backend_address_pool_name`  in the `block2`

How can I do this?

So in the `block2`, is there a way we can refer the values of each iteration as `dynamic.backend_address_pool` and assign to the value `backend_address_pool_name` in `block2` ?

Here's my `variables.tf`

```
variable "backend_pools" {
  type = map(object({
    name         = string
    fqdns        = list(string)
    ip_addresses = list(string)
  }))

  description = "The configuration for backend pools"
}

variable "request_routing_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    rule_type                  = string
    http_listener_name         = string
    backend_address_pool_name  = string
    backend_http_settings_name = string
  }))

  description = "The configuration of routing rules for backend pools"
}
```

here's my `variables.tfvars`

```
backend_pools = {
    pool1 = {
      fqdns        = ["some-value1", "some-value2", "some-value3"]
      ip_addresses = ["10.0.0.0"]
    },
    pool2 = {
      fqdns        = ["some-value1", "some-value2", "some-value3"]
      ip_addresses = ["10.0.0.0"]
    },
    pool3 = {
      fqdns        = ["some-value1", "some-value2", "some-value3"]
      ip_addresses = ["10.0.0.0"]
    }        
}

request_routing_rules = { 
    pool1 = {
      rule_type                  = "Basic"
      http_listener_name         = ""
      backend_address_pool_name  = ""
      backend_http_settings_name = ""
    },
    pool2 = {
      rule_type                  = "Basic"
      http_listener_name         = ""
      backend_address_pool_name  = ""
      backend_http_settings_name = ""
    }
    pool3 = {
      rule_type                  = "Basic"
      http_listener_name         = ""
      backend_address_pool_name  = ""
      backend_http_settings_name = ""
    }        
 }
```

Comment: Could you give an example in the original post of what your variable inputs look like for each dynamic block?

Comment: Thanks, so will `backend_address_pool_name` = `fqdns` in your example or are you just trying to get the name of the pool from `backend_pools` (`pool1`, `pool2`, etc)?

Comment: Yeah trying to get the names of the pools (pool1, pool2, etc)

Comment: The direct answer to your question is in the documentation at: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html. However, matching two `Map` in a nested iterator like that is dangerous, and you should consider nesting the `request_routing_rules` as an `object` inside `backend_pools`. That would be both safer and easier to implement.

Comment: Do you need the variable called `backend_pools`? If not we could just iterate over one variable to make things easier. Essentially you could look at adding `fdqns` and `ip_addresses` into `request_routing_rules` and maybe call the variable itself something more descriptive. Then you could set `backend_address_pool_name = each.key`. Just to make sure there is a 1:1 relation of `pool1` in `backend_pools` to `pool1` in `request_routing_rules` right?

Answer (score 1):

To add onto my comment above you could try something like:

```
backend_pool_and_request_routing_rules = { 
    pool1 = {
      fqdns                     = ["some-value1", "some-value2", "some-value3"]
      ip_addresses               = ["10.0.0.0"]
      rule_type                  = "Basic"
      http_listener_name         = ""
      backend_address_pool_name  = ""
      backend_http_settings_name = ""
    },
```

```
# block one
  dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pool_and_request_routing_rules

    content {
      name      = each.key
      fqdns     = each.value["fqdns"]
      ip_addresses = each.value["ip_addresses"]
    }
  }    

# block two
  dynamic "request_routing_rule" {
    for_each = var.backend_pool_and_request_routing_rules

    content {
      name      = each.key
      rule_type     = each.value["rule_type"]
      http_listener_name = each.value["http_listener_name"]
      backend_address_pool_name = each.key
      backend_http_settings_name = each.value["backend_http_settings_name"]
    }
  }
```